# How to create a toggle button that dynamically changes HTML content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on this question for several days, and have researched it on SO as well as the web at large and was unable to find material that helped me solve it.

I am trying to create a weather app that can toggle the weather units displayed between Fahrenheit and Celsius. I start by appending the weather in Fahrenheit, and then I have created an event handler that conditionally changes the inner content of the associated element based on whether that element is currently displaying "F" or "C".

As it is, my app successfully loads with the Fahrenheit temperature, and toggles to Celsius on click, but it will not toggle back to Fahrenheit. I assume there is some issue with how the events are registered, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
var fahr = document.createElement("a");
fahr.attr = ("href", "#");
fahr.className = "tempUnit";
fahr.innerHTML = tempf + "&deg;F" + "<br/>";
$("#currentWeather").append(fahr);

var cels = document.createElement("a");
cels.attr = ("href", "#");
cels.className = "tempUnit";
cels.innerHTML = tempc + "&deg;C" + "<br/>";

var units = document.getElementsByClassName("tempUnit");

$(".tempUnit").click(function() {
    if (units[0].innerHTML.indexOf("F") != -1) {
        $(".tempUnit").replaceWith(cels);
    } else {
        $(".tempUnit").replaceWith(fahr);
    }
})
```

Thank you so much in advance! Happy to provide additional information if necessary.

Comment: You main problem is that you are assigning a click handler to all elements **currently** on the page with the class `.tempUnit`. After the click happens, you replace those elements with new elements which happen to have the same class `.tempUnit` but weren't captured when you added a click handler because they didn't exist at that time. As **@Satpal** said in his answer, you can **delegate** click handling to the parent element of your `.tempUnit` elements, which will always be there, and handle clicks through it instead of individual `.tempUnit` elements which will get replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a *direct* binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

As you using `replaceWith()`, existing element is replaced with new element and  event handlers are not attached with them.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

*General Syntax*

```
$(parentStaticContainer).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*, Also use `this` i.e. current element context and use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to update `href` element

```
$("#currentWeather").on("click", ".tempUnit", function() {
      if (this.innerHTML.indexOf("F") != -1) {
        $(this).replaceWith(cels);
      }
      else {
        $(this).replaceWith(fahr);
      }
})
```

```js
var tempf = 212;
var tempc = 100;

var fahr = document.createElement("a");
fahr.setAttribute("href", "#");
fahr.className = "tempUnit";
fahr.innerHTML = tempf + "&deg;F" + "<br/>";
$("#currentWeather").append(fahr);

var cels = document.createElement("a");
cels.setAttribute("href", "#");
cels.className = "tempUnit";
cels.innerHTML = tempc + "&deg;C" + "<br/>";

$("#currentWeather").on("click", ".tempUnit", function() {
  if (this.innerHTML.indexOf("F") != -1) {
    $(this).replaceWith(cels);
  } else {
    $(this).replaceWith(fahr);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="currentWeather"></div>
```

Comment: That fixed it! I cannot thank you enough your your prompt and well-explained answer!!

Comment: @fbliss, Glad I could help :)